# value of asp.net textbox is null inside jquery popover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jQuery popover that contains an asp.net textbox and button. I have it submitting but the textboxes value is not coming thru. I had to add UseSubmitBehavior = false to get the button to fire.

Script 
   //

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();

    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();

    },

    open: function () {

        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    }


});

$("#popover-markup").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
//]]>
```

Markup

```
enter code <div class="popover-markup"> 
<a href="#" class="trigger"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" title="Save Grid Layout" style="color:#108ec6; padding:5px;"></i></a> 
<div class="head hide">Save Report</div>
<div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">

      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtReportName"  CssClass="form-control" Width="150px" placeholder="Report Name" data-dismiss="popover" />
    </div>
    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" ID="btnSaveLayout" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveLayout_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="popover"/>

</div>
```

Button Click Event

```
 Protected Sub btnSaveLayout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ReportingDAL.ExecuteNonQuery(ReportingDAL.GetConnection(), "InsertReportGridState", New SqlParameter("@StateString", Session("layout")), New SqlParameter("@ReportName", txtReportName.Text))

    lbLayouts.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: What you have in this `btnSaveLayout_Click`?

Comment: I have been testing your code yesterday and today, and it works, I can get the text in txtReportName, but please post your btnSaveLayout_Click code to see what are you doing

Comment: ReportingDAL.ExecuteNonQuery(ReportingDAL.GetConnection(), "InsertReportGridState", New SqlParameter("@StateString", Session("layout")), New SqlParameter("@ReportName", txtReportName.Text))

        lbLayouts.DataBind()

Comment: Im not doing anything special but no matter what I do I cannot get the value of txtReportName.Text

Comment: Added Button click event